# Size of the mongodb document slows down querying?

Tags: mongodb

We are having a User Model(mongodb), in a social network. There are many properties which are related to user, but all of them are not required every time. So should I store it in the same document, or create a separate Model.

Storing it in the same document increases the size of the document. Does that effect the querying speed? What are the best practices.

Answer (score 0):

I say, extract all rarely accessed data into other documents. Otherwise your user documents will be bloated and that will affect performance. Even if you're smart enough not to transfer them over the wire (using field specification in `find` command), then they are still in the same file, which decreases performance of full scans and increases your working set size without necessity.

Answer (score 0):

You make no hint as to how many fields or the size of each field however, as @Sergio states, large documents can increase your working set and the amount of memory required by the LRU. It could also increase index size for a specific query should you need to index a compound index that covers many of these extra fields, increasing the amount of RAM needed for the index.

However, in terms of speed, MongoDB is fully designed to work in all manners with the maximum document size of 16 meg providing you setup your cluster correctly.

So your main problem here is your memory and space, if you take that into account and work at a optimal rate to it then you should be OK. The main solution, as @Sergio said again, is to denormalise however my main response question would be: how often do you need all the data in that table at the same time?